# How to make a list of things in Java gui

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm writing a small program as practice in java. What I'm trying to do is create a small application which stores information about people: names, addresses, phone numbers etc. I want for the gui to generate a list of all the people stored and display the names on the left side of the gui. The user can then click on a name and the information will be displayed to the right. The information can then be updated by the user. I've created a Jscrollpane to display the list of names. How do I generate the list of names, keeping in mind that people could be added or deleted? Getting names from a file shouldn't be too much trouble but how would I generate the buttons and link them? I am using the gui builder in netbeans to do this

Edit: If you look to the right of this question page you will see a list of related question. If you click on a question, it will take you to the specific page of that question. What I want is similar to this; I want to be able to generate a list of all the people that are already in the database and display them in a list. Then by clicking on a person, the user will be able to see that person's information.

Comment: A little bit of code of what have you done could be very helpfull

Comment: [It's already written about](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) (and elsewhere). The only 'bridge' then is turning the data-source (ie. file) into the appropriate model or otherwise loading the values in the Swing control.

Comment: The Jlist looks promising. I think that might be exactly what I need. Thank you. Though you didn't reply as an answer so I can't close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Jtextfield for each field, such as name, address, phone number. I'd probably put a JLabel in front so the user knows what each field is for. Then at the bottom, put a Button, and implement an actionlistener that that grabs the text from each field. Have you tried anything at all? Where are you running into problems?

Comment: I already have all of that. Inputting the information and storing it isn't a problem. I want to give the user the ability to select an already existing person from a list. I am not sure how to generate that list since that requires generating buttons dynamically based on how many people are stored in the database. I'll edit my question to elaborate on this

Comment: your question originally did not reflect this. You will need to post some code for what you have tried in order for us to help you as it matters if the GUI must be updated dynamically or not.

Comment: as I mentioned in my post, I am using the gui builder in netbeans which is automatically generating code for me. So I haven't really written any code yet. Since I am still build the gui, I haven't even put in the code for listeners. Creating this list will be the first bit of code I will be doing. I think Nabeel Omer has the right idea, provided it is actually possible fill an arraylist with buttons

Comment: Even then, you should still be able to view your actual java code I think it's a button in the bottom of the GUI builder.  If I was you, I would work on adding the people first, then it will be easier, once they are there to remove them.

Comment: Have you looked at building a JList? Then in the JList add the list or arraylist that nabeel was talking about. In the array list, use the .add(name) to add a string of the customers name. You can then see what is selected in the JList and remove that from the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

For creating buttons, you should do some tutorials on simple java gui, there are heaps out there just google java gui tutorial.
For retrieving information, you should be using an ActionListener, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) is a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a basic idea, but you will have to code for yourself.

Use an `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`. The `<String>` thingies are called generics, just ignore them right now. After this you can do `list.add(""):` and `list.remove()`. You will have to write the GUI too. For that,have a look at some tutorials.

Comment: So basically go through my database and create an arraylist of buttons and fill their text field with the names. Once that button is clicked, I update the window to display the person associated with that button. Did I understand that right?

Comment: @Aeleon No no not an arraylist of buttons! Ok wait, first tell me what kind of database are we talking about?

Comment: @Aeleon what you do is, you instantiate a list, you create your GUI then when the user presses a button to add information, you do list.add() when the user wants to remove information, you do list.remove() and so on.

Comment: My professor mentioned something about serializable object. I don't fully understand them yet but that is probably what I will be using. I will be storing all the objects in binary form when the window is closed and reloading them when the application is opened again